# (Keycloak) Freemarker Template system properties and environment variables

Tags: jboss, wildfly, freemarker, keycloak, system-properties

We wanted to work on the Templates and tried to get the system properties that we set earlier in the standalone.xml file like this.

```
</extensions>
<system-properties>
    <property name="testProp" value="TestVal"/>
</system-properties>
```

In the Docs of Keycloak its described like the following.

- ${some.system.property} - for system properties
- ${env.ENV_VAR} - for environment variables.

But nothing worked for us. We always get the following error Message “An internal server error has occurred”.
What is the right way to get the system properties and the environment variables in the Freemarker Template?

Comment: I don't know Keycloak, but certainly it helps in getting answer if you provide the exception message and maybe stack trace (find it in the log files), and if the error is inside the template, then the relevant part of the template.

Answer (score 8):

[Keycloak Theme Property Documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#theme-properties)
is missing how to add them in the template.
It is however [just a bit lower in the same document](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_custom_user_attributes)

So in `theme.properties` could be

```
customPropInThemeProperties=${env.SOME_OTHER_RESOURCE_URL}
```

Then uses in `.ftl` as

```
${properties.customPropInThemeProperties}
```

Comment: I have .env in login folder and used exactly what you write here. But it does not work. Please explain a bit more if there is an additional step ?

Answer (score 2):

In order to use system properties in the freemarker template of keycloak, do the following configuration.

Declare your system properties in the `standalone.xml`

```
<system-properties>        
        <property name="UATLogin" value="http://localhost:9090" />
</system-properties>
```

Add variable inside theme.properties to access the system property.

```
   UATURL=${UATLogin}
```

As an example, I have done the testing with `register.ftl`

```
<span><a href="${properties.UATURL}">${kcSanitize(msg("backToLogin"))?no_esc}</a></span>
```